# Uncheck/Reset Radio Button through MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

How to uncheck/Reset/clear selection for a group of radio buttons,which are under same Group Name

how can i achieve this in MVVM ?

**Edit 1 :**

```
 <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" GroupName = "TransactSelect" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOnlyEnabled}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOnlyCancelVoidChecked}"></RadioButton>
 <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" GroupName = "TransactSelect" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOnlyEnabled}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOnlySuspiciousChecked}"></RadioButton>
 <RadioButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" GroupName = "TransactSelect" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOnlyEnabled}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOnlyDirectDebitChecked}"></RadioButton>
```

Comment: What does the binding look like?

Comment: Please Look the Sample

Comment: Would anything be wrong with just resetting `IsOnlyCancelVoidChecked`, `IsOnlySuspiciousChecked ` and `IsOnlyDirectDebitChecked ` in code? Or are you looking for generic code to dynamically find/reset all check boxes by group name?

Comment: In View Model if i just keep IsOnlyCancelVoidChecked, IsOnlySuspiciousChecked and IsOnlyDirectDebitChecked to "false" means radio buttons will be not unchecked thats is the problem  i am facing

Comment: Are you implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)?

Comment: yes i am using INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Then I cannot obviously see how they would fail to update when you set the properties to false. Maybe someone else can see something I don't :)

Comment: @user861995 Well the important question now is, how are you using it? Are you raising the change in the setter? Is the binding working at all? Check the output and/or add PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to your binding. Also you could use snoop to check if the DataContext is what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have solved my problem using the below link . There is some problem with Radio Button Binding thorugh MVVM.

Known Issue Discussed in the Below Link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8eb8280a-19c4-4502-8260-f74633a9e2f2/

so , i followed **karliwatson** Strategy from the Below Link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8eb8280a-19c4-4502-8260-f74633a9e2f2/

Comment: Alternative Approaches http://www.phdesign.com.au/programming/wpf-radiobutton-binding-to-ischecked-property/